TikZ node not lining up
I am trying to add a couple of nodes using TikZ.
As you can see in the screenshot the second line
is offset to the left.
I cannot see what is causing this. Does anyone have any ideas?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={280mm, 194mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,shapes,calc,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myinnersep}{2}% inner sep in mm


% section heading
\newcommand{\myheadingbox}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=white, rounded corners]{%
        \tikz[baseline] \node [#1,rectangle, minimum width = 26.7cm, draw]{#2};}%

\begin{document}

\myheadingbox{A. Main Heading}\\
\myheadingbox{1.Particulars of the Subject}


\end{document}


It is not related to TikZ, but with the par indent. Try \noindent\myheadingbox{A. Main Heading}\\ \myheadingbox{1.Particulars of the Subject}

The offset is caused by a non-zero \parindent in the main body of the document. The following will solve it:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={280mm, 194mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,shapes,calc,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myinnersep}{2}% inner sep in mm


% section heading
\newcommand{\myheadingbox}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=white, rounded corners]{%
        \tikz[baseline] \node [#1,rectangle, minimum width = 26.7cm, draw]{#2};}%

\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt

\myheadingbox{A. Main Heading}\\
\myheadingbox{1.Particulars of the Subject}


\end{document}

If you prefer to maintain a non-zero \parindent in your document, then you can use \noindent prior to any line that is at the beginning of a paragraph:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={280mm, 194mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,arrows.meta,shapes,calc,shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myinnersep}{2}% inner sep in mm


% section heading
\newcommand{\myheadingbox}[2][rectangle,draw,fill=white, rounded corners]{%
        \tikz[baseline] \node [#1,rectangle, minimum width = 26.7cm, draw]{#2};}%

\begin{document}
%\parindent 0pt

\noindent\myheadingbox{A. Main Heading}\\
\myheadingbox{1.Particulars of the Subject}

\end{document}


You should really remove the first suggestion of setting \parindent=0pt, that's altering the entire document, using \noindent is the correct approach here.

That would assume that the originator knew about \parindent. Since \parindent is a very basic and common configuration I did not think it proper to assume they even knew it was in effect (I believe the default is 10pt).

Since your problem is already solved by comments just some of-topic suggestion how to make your code simpler and more clear:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape,
            total={280mm, 194mm}]{geometry}
% section heading
\newcommand{\myheadingbox}[1]{\noindent%
        \tikz[baseline] \node[draw, rounded corners,
                              minimum width=267mm,
                              inner sep=2mm] {#1};}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\myheadingbox{A. Main Heading}\\
\myheadingbox{1.Particulars of the Subject}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


